# Authenticating location result

Tags: android, authentication, location

I have developed a location based service which identifies the location of the user using GPS. I want to authenticate the data from GPS because an attacker can spoof location information with a simulator.

I've studied an authenticating mechanism from [here](http://airccse.org/journal/ijsptm/papers/1612ijsptm02.pdf), but i don't know how to implement the technique they have mentioned.

Comment: if the attacker owns the device there's nothing stopping them spoofing both cell and gps location data. It might be harder but it's possible and hence not a reliable mechanism for authentication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of the paper is to retrieve geolocation from two different providers. In your case you'd get the device's GPS position for high accuracy and the cell id position to validate this data.

Here's a full example how to get locations by cell id: http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40524

You need to define a threshold for the difference of these locations. So we believe the GPS location is faked when the distance between GPS and cellular is greater than our threshold.

Some abstract code example:

```
static final int THRESHOLD = 2000 // maximum discrepancy in meters

Location getLocationFromGPS();
Location getCellularLocation();

boolean isLocationValid(Location gps) {
    Location cell = getCellularLocation();
    return gps.distanceTo(cell) <= THRESHOLD;
}
```

Following this approach there can be two different types of mistakes:

1. assuming the GPS data is faked but it is not
2. trust the GPS data while it's faked

Setting small values for `THRESHOLD` will more and more lead to mistake #1. Most of all users will never fake their GPS data, so claiming they're cheaters won't make your app successful ;-)

The paper states that the Cellular Network Based accuracy is about 100 - 1500 meters. So I highly recommend you to choose values greater than 1500 meters.

Please mind that - as Rune FS mentioned - advanced users may fake both location providers at the same time.

Comment: Thank you! it's really useful. But it checks only the integrity of location data. I want to authenticate the user who is using that app. Is there any authenticating mechanisms available?